# Vue doesn't update props data on array change in for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have elements made in for loop like

```
 <b-card v-for="(campaign, i) in settingsData.campaigns" v-bind:key="i"> 
  <countdown :startDate="campaign.startDate"        
             :period="campaign.period"         
             :time="campaign.hour_every_nth"         
             :end="campaign.endDate"> 
  </countdown> 

  <b-button @click="onClickDeleteCampaign(i)">DELETE</b-button>
</b-card>
```

And let's say I removed an item from `settingsData.campaigns` using code below:

```
onClickDeleteCampaign(index) {
  this.settingsData.campaigns.splice(index, 1);
}
```

It actually removes the item from `settingsData.campaigns` but the data I provided to `countdown` like `startDate`, `period`, `time`, `end` doesn't update at all and it gets overwrote by the data that has removed by the code.

How can I resolve this issue?

GIF:
https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/LeafyFearlessGreatdane

Comment: It just looks like u are removing wrong item . Post the code for remove button both html and js.

Comment: @Aldarund I just updated the code, and as I mentioned, It removes a correct item but the data for `countdown` component doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<b-card v-for="(campaign, i) in settingsData.campaigns" v-bind:key="i">` and use `campaign` instead of `settingsData.campaigns[i]`.

This means that you are iterating over the `Array`/`Object`: `settingsData.campaigns`. `campaign` will be the current campaign and `i` will be the index of that campaign.

You are trying to iterate over the property `length` instead of an actual Object or Array.

Comment: then how can I remove an item from `settingsData.campaigns`? I have a button that removes its item like this but I'm not sure how I can remove an item using it.
`<b-button variant="danger" @click="onClickDeleteCampaign(campaign)">
                DELETE
              </b-button>


onClickDeleteCampaign(campaign) { this.settingsData.campaigns.splice(index, 1)
}`

Comment: I'm still getting into the same situation from the GIF I posted